# Hidden Markov Model toolbox/library

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, hidden-markov-models

I am now trying to use hidden markov model for my project, and I searched the Internet, and found a lot of hidden markov model implementations either in MATLAB or in C/C++. In fact Matlab provides a statistics toolbox, which includes an implementation of hidden markov model. I am a newbie in this field, and I was wondering which toolbox or library is the best one. Is it wise to purchase the statistic toolbox for hidden markov model? Moreover, I plan to use this model in the context of image processing. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend Kevin Murphy's HMMToolbox, or its successor PMTK. But this is a rather subjective question, as it is now I expect it will be closed (see [**the FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must understand about hidden markov model first

here's a good paper about Hidden Markov Model for speech recognition

> http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf

for matlab implementation you can refer to the matlab official documentation

> http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html

and if you want to implement it in C you can see a very good example here

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69647/Hidden-Markov-Models-in-C

if you want to ask me something about Hidden Markov Model I'll gladly will help you but I think you should understand the basic first,then if you have any question you can ask me in the comment or e-mail me (you can see it in my profile)
I hope this answer helps you :)